# Unexpected results from re_match in GNU regex.h, am I missing something?

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to do some pattern matching with GNU's regex.h.  I've been able to reproduce what is happening with a simple example as follows:

```
    #include <regex.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main() {
            char pat[] = "[Mm]ark";
            char name[] = "Mark";

            struct re_pattern_buffer pat_buff;
            pat_buff.translate = 0;
            pat_buff.fastmap = 0;
            pat_buff.buffer = 0;
            pat_buff.allocated = 0;

            re_syntax_options = RE_SYNTAX_EGREP;

            printf("Ret value from re_compile_pattern: %d\n", re_compile_pattern(pat, strlen(pat), &pat_buff));

            printf("Ret value from re_match: %d\n", re_match(&pat_buff, name, strlen(name), 0, NULL));

            regfree(&pat_buff);

            return 0; 
}
```

re_compile_pattern() returns 0 as expected.
re_match() returns -1 and this is contrary to what I would expect.

Can anyone give me any pointers or show me what I am missing?

Comment: `re_*` are the nonstandard, GNU-specific interface to regex. You really should be using the POSIX `regcomp` and `regexec` functions.

Comment: OK. So moving forward I will consider switching, but I want to make this code work first before I overhaul.

Comment: No problem. That's why I wrote it as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't compile your code on my Fedora 10 box.  Instead I tried reworking it to use the POSIX regcomp() and regexec() API as R.. suggested above.  I know this doesn't quite answer your question regarding the GNU API, but the following code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

char *default_pattern = "[Mm]ark";
char *default_string = "youMarkmywords";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   int ret;
   regex_t preg;
   char *pattern = default_pattern;
   char *string = default_string;

   if (argc >= 3) {
      pattern = argv[1];
      string = argv[2];
   }   

   ret = regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB);
   if (0 != ret) {
      fprintf(stderr, "regcomp failed to compile %s\n", pattern);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }   

   ret = regexec(&preg, string, 0, NULL, 0); 
   if (0 == ret) {
      printf("Input \"%s\" matched pattern \"%s\"\n", pattern, string);
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Input \"%s\" didn't match pattern \"%s\"\n", pattern, string);
   }   

   regfree(&preg);
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Even though, strictly speaking, this didn't not answer my question, you gave a very helpful and specific, detailed workaround when no others were forthcoming. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the intermediate steps, i.e. the compilation, succeed. You should probably pass `strlen(pat)` rather than `sizeof pat` to `re_compile_pattern()`.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it to pass strlen(pat) to re_compile_pattern() and also confirmed that, indeed, re_compile_pattern() is working (returning 0). Still doesn't work.